# Connect Samsung galaxy tab to projector

Tags: hdmi, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I have Samsung Galaxy tab P3100 tab. I want to connect it to Projector for presentation. I searched a lot but din't get any solution. Does any one knows is it possible to connect it to projector? If yes then what accessories I need and what's the procedure?

Comment: That very much depends on the projector. Do your tab *and* the projector have a HDMI port? That would be my first check. I guess you don't want to carry another "intermediary" device around, and thus are looking for a direct connection, right?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find any specific accessories on the official samsung product page. However a TV-OUT Cable exists which presumable (if the projector has all the necessary inputs) can also be used to show the picture from the tab on the projector:

Product Name: [Samsung ECC1TP0BBEGSTA Galaxy Tab TV Out Cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004DFADZK)

Unfortunately the cable doesn't offer hdmi - output: only RCA Video.

An HDMI Adapter for the Galaxy TAB Series exists but it's not compatible with your specific model (Galaxy TAB 2 7.0) see the following product [page](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005KBOFZU)

Answer (score 1):

The Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 P3100 has no capability to connect to an external display.  The necessary hardware was not included in that model.

source : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=37032295&postcount=110

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a special adapter for that.  You need this:

[Samsung P4 P5 HDTV Adapter for Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, Galaxy Tab 8.9, Galaxy Tab 7.7 and Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005TLKR1C)

[SANOXY® Black HDMI Input to VGA Adapter Converter For PC / Laptop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007KFVQXI)

[6FT SVGA VGA Monitor MM Male To Male Extension Cable 80](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006HXUXRY)

If the projector has an HDMI slot then you don't need the HDMI to VGA and the VGA to VGA,  You just need to use the Samsung EPL-3PHPBEGXAR Galaxy Tab HDTV Adapter and then an HDMI cable.